# Match two data based on the row name

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have two data frames that I want to match the row name with,

the first consist of

```
"Pop1_lepro001" "Pop1_lepro002" "Pop1_lepro004" "Pop1_lepro005" "Pop1_lepro006"
"Pop1_lepro007" "Pop1_lepro008" "Pop1_lepro009" "Pop1_lepro010" "Pop1_lepro011"
"Pop1_lepro012" "Pop1_lepro013" "Pop1_lepro014" "Pop1_lepro015" "Pop1_lepro016"...
```

it has 258 data

and second

```
"Pop1_lepro001" "Pop1_lepro002" "Pop1_lepro004" "Pop1_lepro005" "Pop1_lepro006"
"Pop1_lepro007" "Pop1_lepro008" "Pop1_lepro009" "Pop1_lepro010" "Pop1_lepro011"
"Pop1_lepro012" "Pop1_lepro013" "Pop1_lepro014" "Pop1_lepro015" "Pop1_lepro016"...
```

it has 268 data

I would like to exclude the unused line in 2nd data based on the first data,

I am currently beginning of this and need idea to solve this,

kindly appreciate your help.

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two-step: first is to bring the row names into the frame itself, which enables the second step: merge/join the data (see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272)) for much more information on the merge/join mechanics).

Demonstration using subsets of `mtcars`:

## base R

```r
df1$rowname <- rownames(df1)
df2$rowname <- rownames(df2)
merge(df1, df2, by = "rowname", all = TRUE)
#             rowname  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs
# 1        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1
# 2        Duster 360   NA  NA   NA  NA 3.21 3.570 15.84  0
# 3    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110   NA    NA    NA NA
# 4 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0
# 5         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0
# 6     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0
# 7         Merc 240D   NA  NA   NA  NA 3.69 3.190 20.00  1
# 8           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1
```

## dplyr

(Starting with fresh versions of `df1` and `df2`, no `$rowname` column.)

```r
library(dplyr)
full_join(
  rownames_to_column(df1), 
  rownames_to_column(df2),
  by = "rowname")
#             rowname  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs
# 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0
# 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0
# 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1
# 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110   NA    NA    NA NA
# 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0
# 6           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1
# 7        Duster 360   NA  NA   NA  NA 3.21 3.570 15.84  0
# 8         Merc 240D   NA  NA   NA  NA 3.69 3.190 20.00  1
```

---

Sample data:

```r
df1 <- mtcars[1:6, 1:4]
df2 <- mtcars[c(1:3, 5:8), 5:8]
df1
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105
df2
#                   drat    wt  qsec vs
# Mazda RX4         3.90 2.620 16.46  0
# Mazda RX4 Wag     3.90 2.875 17.02  0
# Datsun 710        3.85 2.320 18.61  1
# Hornet Sportabout 3.15 3.440 17.02  0
# Valiant           2.76 3.460 20.22  1
# Duster 360        3.21 3.570 15.84  0
# Merc 240D         3.69 3.190 20.00  1
```

Comment: that is very helpful! and can I also remove the row in df1 that is not existed in df2 without joining them?

Comment: Yes. What we did here is called a "full join" or "outer join", where all rows are retained even when one of the frames does not have the keys. What you're asking for is a right-join (`df1` is left, `df2` is right), where all rows from the right-hand side of the join are retained but only matching rows from the LHS. Some links that do a great job explaining these differences: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272. Bottom line: use `right_join(..)` from dplyr, or `merge(df1, df2, by="rowname", all.y=TRUE)`.